# Add Script Reference (JavaScript) to Script Manager on Microsoft AJAX Partial Postback

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, microsoft-ajax

I am trying to add a script reference to the script manager in the event of a Microsoft AJAX Partial Postback, ie a user clicks on a link in an Update Panel.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Page, Page.GetType(), "UniqueName",
                                          Page.ResolveUrl(scriptPath));
```

Doesn't work and either does

```
ScriptReference script = new ScriptReference(scriptPath);
MyScriptManager.Scripts.Add(script);
```

From what I have read on the net, RegisterClientScriptInclude should work even in a partial postback.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/addingCssJsAjaxPartialPos.aspx

Can anyone give any ideas why these don't work, or another way to do it?

**EDIT:** Additional information.
I am working with a very large legacy code base that has the forms and script manager in each page rather than in the master page. I would like to place the code into a class and use the following call to add the javascript effect.

```
ClientSideScripts.BackgroundColourFade(Page, ScriptManager, Control);
```

The reasons I want to include the script in the method call is

1. Consumes of the method don't have to remember to include the script
2. Changing the script used only requires a change in one place
3. Only include the javascript when needed to keep the load time of the page down

Comment: Have a look at this SO-Question because it might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916618/scriptmanager-registerclientscriptinclude-does-not-work-in-updatepanel/1916727#1916727

Comment: @Tim while that is an elegant solution to the problem, I'm working with legacy code and it will be painful to implement in my situation. I will update my question to explain further.

Comment: @Tim I completely misunderstood http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916618/scriptmanager-registerclientscriptinclude-does-not-work-in-updatepanel/1916727#1916727, I have tried it and it works. Can you provide it as an answer so I mark the questions as answered please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this SO-Question because it answers your question:

- [ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude does not work in UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916618/scriptmanager-registerclientscriptinclude-does-not-work-in-updatepanel/1916727#1916727)

> ```
> function dynamic() {
>   alert('dynamic');
>   $('#divDyn').text('Dynamic!');
> }
> // notify that the script has been loaded <-- new!
> if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined') Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
> ```